# Can DM script read images with the same extension (like *.mrc) from a folder?

Tags: dm-script

I have a bunch of `MRC` images saved in a folder. I want my `DM` script to read and process them one by one. Now I just open some of them (like 20 images) at once and use `FindNextImage` in my script to sequentially process them.

I am wondering if I can define a path and let `DM` script go to this path to read out the `MRC` images one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with the function GetFilesInDirectory.  An example of its use was posted with the answer to the following question:

[Opening multiple files from folder ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713158/opening-multiple-files-from-folder-in-digitalmicrograph-scripting?rq=1)

An example of how to extract the files with a particular file type extension was given in the answer to this question:

[How could I open more than one image ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764198/how-could-i-open-more-than-one-image-with-a-single-dialog-in-digital-micrograph)

In particular, have a close look at the method CreateFilteredFileList.