# Making movie with bunch of dm3 files

Tags: dm-script

I'm looking for a script which can make lots of dm3 files in to single movie file(stack)

I found there is a script that function as exactly what I want, but to make a movie through this script first I have to import all the dm3 files in order on GMS and excute the script. (Here is the link for reference : http://www.dmscripting.com/movie_creator_and_player.html)

Problem is, I got so many dm3 files to make a movie, over 100,000. So during importing all the dm3 files, my computer is frozen because of the heavy load.

So I would like to want some modified script which doesn't need any importing source files and can just return the result, movie. It would be great like importing source process is just selecting dm3 files in folders sorted with time, alphabet name or whatever.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackExchange. Please be aware, that this is a forum for seeking advice on coding questions, not to find ready-made solutions or ask others to do them for you. So while questions like "With what command do I import images..." or "How do I process all images of a folder..." etc are on-topic, your question is rather off-topic and usually not well received on site.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this question on reading multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26713158/1302888) or [this question on processing file-strings from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27764198/1302888)

Comment: A source of "read-made scripts" is the [DM scripting database at FELMI](https://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm-script/), but I don't know if anything like you've asked for exists on that site.

Comment: @DonghoonLEE sorry to be slow with my comment, but I have a (free) demo app made with my Enabler framework for DM-script that will display all the images in a folder via successive updates to an image window, much like a movie.  This demo app does not need to load all the images into DM memory first.  You can use a third-party screen-capture app to generate a free standing movie from this playback.  If you are interested, please contact me via the info email address posted on the Web page given in my StackOverflow profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create "movies" from DM3 images as a stack, you will always require the full memory of all these images, because such a stack - other than a video codec movie file like mpeg, avi, etc. - does not have any compression added.

So, if you want to stick 100000 images in a "movie stack" it will require 100000x the memory of a single image plus the according "read & write" time. There will be no DM script working around this.

What you possible *can* do, is to write a script which automatically opens and adds images to a stack from a folder without the need of opening them a single, separate image first and adding it to a stack thereafter. (I have not checked what the script you've linked to actually does. It might do this already?)

An alternative approach for *DM3 files --> Movie* is to batch-convert the DM3 files in a generally acknowledged image format like TIF and then use different software which can do *Image-Series --> Stack* or *Image-Series --> Movie* conversion. I've used *ImageJ* in the past for this purpose, but there might be better solutions out there. This, however, is a topic outside the scope of this StackOverflow discussion.

Comment: Thank you for answering. First I have to say sorry that I misunderstand purpose of this site. I'll try to figure out which way is available. In a high chance, I may create the script myself. But honestly, I have no experience of coding.. I'm just a chemical engineer using TEM. So would you recommend any site to learn DM script for beginner?

Comment: @DonghoonLEE What version of GMS do you use? The "F1" help documentation is a good starting point, but it is a lot better in GMS 3 than it was in GMS 2 or GMS 1. Otherwise *here* is a good site - if you have coding questions (also beginner level), ask them here. Try to keep the scope limited (more questions are better than long questions). As for other documentation: You can visit [Gatan's scripting page](http://www.gatan.com/resources/scripts) and the **external links** listed there, like [this for a PDF](http://dmscript.tavernmaker.de) or [this for examples](http://www.dmscripting.com)